# How to set value in the other text field when dropdown list selected?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

i got some problem, when dropdown is selected i wanna set value in the other field.

I tried this html :

```
<select id="nik" name="nik" class="select-select2" style="width: 100%;" onchange="setData('<?php echo $data['nama_jabatan']; ?>','<?php echo $data['nilai_tunjangan_p']; ?>','<?php echo $data['nilai_tunjangan_j']; ?>')">
```

and this js :

```
 function setData(nama_jabatan,nilai_tunjangan_p,nilai_tunjangan_j)
 {
    $('#nama_jabatan').val(nama_jabatan);
    $('#nilai_tunjangan_p').val(nilai_tunjangan_p);
    $('#nilai_tunjangan_j').val(nilai_tunjangan_j);
}
```

But the text box val is not updated.

Comment: Can you show the relevant rendered source code please? without seeing/knowing what your `php` is outputting it's difficult to help you.

Comment: Please add more data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to add the information on the `<option>` and not on the `<select>` tag. You can use jQuery `data-`.

Like:

```
<option value="volvo" data-nama_jabatan="nama_jabatan 1" data-nilai_tunjangan_p="nilai_tunjangan_p 1" data-nilai_tunjangan_j="nilai_tunjangan_j 1">Volvo</option>
```

Here is a snippet"

```js
$(function(){

    //Add event listener to element with id nik
    $("#nik").change(function(){

         //Get the selected option
         var opt = $(this).find("option:selected")

         //Get the data information from the selected option
         var nama_jabatan = $(opt).data("nama_jabatan");
         var nilai_tunjangan_p = $(opt).data("nilai_tunjangan_p");
         var nilai_tunjangan_j = $(opt).data("nilai_tunjangan_j");
  
         //Update the textboxes
         $('#nama_jabatan').val( nama_jabatan );
         $('#nilai_tunjangan_p').val( nilai_tunjangan_p );
         $('#nilai_tunjangan_j').val( nilai_tunjangan_j );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="nik" name="nik" class="select-select2" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="volvo" data-nama_jabatan="" data-nilai_tunjangan_p="" data-nilai_tunjangan_j=""></option>
    <option value="volvo" data-nama_jabatan="nama_jabatan 1" data-nilai_tunjangan_p="nilai_tunjangan_p 1" data-nilai_tunjangan_j="nilai_tunjangan_j 1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab" data-nama_jabatan="nama_jabatan 2" data-nilai_tunjangan_p="nilai_tunjangan_p 2" data-nilai_tunjangan_j="nilai_tunjangan_j 2">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes" data-nama_jabatan="nama_jabatan 3" data-nilai_tunjangan_p="nilai_tunjangan_p 3" data-nilai_tunjangan_j="nilai_tunjangan_j 3">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi" data-nama_jabatan="nama_jabatan 4" data-nilai_tunjangan_p="nilai_tunjangan_p 4" data-nilai_tunjangan_j="nilai_tunjangan_j 4">Audi</option>
</select>

<br />
<br /><input type="text" id="nama_jabatan">
<br /><input type="text" id="nilai_tunjangan_p">
<br /><input type="text" id="nilai_tunjangan_j">
```

Comment: Nice solution. Here is an addition to your answer. [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/g4ht8kq0/)

Comment: sorry i forgot add <option> on <select>.
on the <select> I use this :
<?php
foreach ($karyawan as $value) {
echo"<option value='".$value['nik']."'>".$value['nik'], ' - ', $value['nama_peg_akte']."</option>";
}
?>

Comment: @rizalfauza, is it working now, or you are still having some issues?